# Different queryNorm values in the result for the same query

Tags: elasticsearch

The following query https://gist.github.com/anonymous/be27203a578494566a35 gives the following result set https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6935100dbf76b9a8f3e3. The documents has been indexed with the these settings https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ca42a7f67c7281935950.

As you can see, the queryNorm value for the documents in the result set varies. But according to the documentation (taken from http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html#query-norm):

> The same query normalization factor is applied to every document and you have no way of changing it. For all intents and purposes, it can be ignored.

Unfortunately, since this does not seem to be true (or maybe I have misunderstood something), I do not get the desired result set for the query above. More specifically, I would expect the second document to have a higher relevance than the first, since there is a higher boosting factor if the query matches the "name" field compared to the "subtype" field. But, because the queryNorm factor is lower for the second document, the relevance score gets in total lower.

Why does the queryNorm behave this way?
Is there really no way of disabled it? (i.e setting the factor to 1)

I am running version 1.4.0 of Elasticsearch.

Comment: Restarting my Mac solved the issue with the queryNorms having different values in the result set. I assume it would have worked with only restarting ES as well.